# Getting LoggedIn User Info Outside Grails Application Context with Spring Security Core PlugIn

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails, spring-security

I am working on Grails Application with Spring Security Core PlugIn. I want to access the currently loggedIn user info with Spring Security Core outside the grails application context/controller scope. Can anyone please tell me that how can we get the information regarding currently loggedIn user info outside controller. I want to access this information in resources/services directory of grails application.

I tried this using: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().principal.username;
But I get Anonymous authentication with **grails.anonymous.user**

I tried another way too for this using httpSession:

```
 HttpSession session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()

 session.properties.each {
      println it;
 }

 SpringSecurityUtils.getSecurityContext(session).authentication.principal
```

But by this way too I couldn't get the Currently LoggedIn User Info. Because httpSession object didn't contain attribute 'SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY'.

Anybody tell me that how may I access this information in my desired directories ?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

Actually Spring Security uses `HttpSession` to store `SecurityContext`, so you can access it everywhere you can access `HttpSession` or `HttpServletRequest`:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext)httpSession.getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
def username = securityContext.getAuthentication().principal.username
```

`SecurityContextHolder` by default uses `ThreadLocal` variable to store context, so if you are retrieving information from another thread, it couldn't get any information and will create empty context. That's one of the possible reasons you've got anonymous authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, How we can access httpsession which may contain attribute 'SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY' too. As I tried too get httpsession by: RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession();

But, this doesn't contain this attribute

Comment: Please See my edited question. There I have added that how I tried to get the HttpSession Object and still couldn't get the LoggedIn user info

Comment: Please also provide in the question a concrete place from which you are trying to retrieve user info using HttpSession.

Comment: I have mentioned in question too. I want to access information of Currently LoggedIn User in resources, services and src directories of grails application. And I am sure there will be same mechanism for accessing this info in all places other than controllers and views.

Answer (score 0):

I think jasp explained a little bit. You can access the getAuthentication().principal.username from outside grails provided that you pass the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest object that you obtained from controllers or filters as entry point.

### For code in src/groovy and src/java:

Say you have a class named `ExampleClazz.groovy` in `src/groovy`

```
package com.test
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository

class ExampleClazz {

    def receiveRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request){
        def userDetails = request.getSession().getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY)

        if(userDetails){
            println userDetails.getAuthentication().principal.username
            return userDetails.getAuthentication().principal.username

        }else{
            return null
        }
    }

}
```

To call this custom class, you register your bean in `resource.groovy`

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
import com.test.ExampleClazz
beans = {
    sampleBean(ExampleClazz)
}
```

To call the ExampleClazz, you can inject it either in controller or filter.
In Filter:

```
class ExampleFilters {
   def sampleBean
   def filters = {
        // your filters here

        someURIs(controller:'securepage',action:'index') {
            before = {
                println "before request"
                println sampleBean.receiveRequest(request) //<--the HttpServletRequest
            }
        }
   }
}
```

In Controller:

```
package com.test

class SomeController {
    def sampleBean
    def index() { 
        sampleBean.receiveRequest(request)//<--the HttpServletRequest

    }
}
```

The same concept goes for services. Just remember to pass the request object obtained from controllers as parameters in services.